# Invalid hook call error with React JS and Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I am stuck in an annoying problem:
I get data from a rest service (I used both a class and a function) and it is working fine if I call the function from the root app.
So I tried to call my function from a button (onClick) inside another component ...and I got:

"Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons..."

I browsed the forum ...a lot of people with similar problem but no solution
Could you help me?

````
import axios from "axios";

import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import ModifyItem from './modifyItem';

export default function Pippo(props) {

const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState();

console.log(props);

  useEffect(() => {
    const table="table="+props.table;
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/getTable',table).then(response => {
      setTableData(response.data);
      setLoading(false);
      console.log(props);
      console.log(tableData);
    });
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div className="testa" > Loading... </div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="testa" >
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <Table size="small" aria-label="a dense table">
          <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
              {tableData.fields.map((f, idx)=>{return (<TableCell key={idx}>{f.COLUMN_NAME}</TableCell>);})}
              </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
              {tableData.data.map((r, ridx)=>{
                  let re = Object.values(r);
                  return (
                      <TableRow key={ridx} onClick={()=>ModifyItem(re)}>
                      { re.map((d, didx)=>{return(<TableCell key={didx}>{d}</TableCell>)}) }
                      </TableRow>
                  );
              })}
          </TableBody>
          </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </div>
  );
}```


The error is reported on the useState call:

    >   12 |
      13 | export default function Pippo(props) {
      14 |
    > 15 | const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
      16 | const [tableData, setTableData] = useState();
      17 |
      18 | console.log(props);

and here the piece of code making the call:


return (
        <List>
        { tables.map((e)=>(
            <ListItem button key={e} onClick={()=>{Pippo({'table': e})}} >
                <ListItemIcon>
                    <TableChartIcon size="large" />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={e.replace(/_/g," ")} />
            </ListItem>
            ))
        }
        </List>
    );
````

Comment: Pippo is a component, and you're trying to instantiate it in an onClick handler. I think this is confusing the compiler, esp the execution of the hooks. Regardless, I'm not really sure what you are expecting to happen. When you click the ListItem button, where should the div from Pippo go?

Comment: I have a specific <div id="xx"> inside the page. In my tests I tried to use also ReactDOM to render on that specific div. But the problem is on the hook. I guess you are right but so which is the correct way to handle this situation? Could you point me in the right direction? Thanks for your help

Comment: A component with hooks cannot be called as a function. Try to mount it as a component instead like `onClick={()=> <Pippo table={e} /> }`

Comment: It doesn't work (the component is not called)

Comment: The component not mounting is a different problem. That can be answered only after looking at how `ListItem` renders `Pippo`.

Answer (score 0):

You have declare `Pippo` as function component.
**Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.**
So you should not call function component like a normal function.

Example you can use a state for table:

```
const [table, setTable] = useState(null);

return (
    <List>
        { tables.map((e)=>(
            <ListItem button key={e} onClick={()=>{setTable(e)}} >
                <ListItemIcon>
                    <TableChartIcon size="large" />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={e.replace(/_/g," ")} />
            </ListItem>
        ))
        }
        
        {/*render Pippo here as exmaple how to call a function component*/}
        {table && <Pippo table={table}}
    </List>
);
```

Comment: I am working on that idea: I put the [table, setTable] at the top oh hierarchy and used the same onClick funcrion.  The component Pippo is called (the console.log at the top is executed) but then nothing happens (...also the following console.log are not executed)

Comment: ...no way. The problem seems to be  useEffect. The second time the component is called, useEffect is not executed.   ...but without useEffect it is useState that does not work ...frustrated

Comment: Yes, you should set second param of useEffect is props.table to make sure table change and api is recalled

Comment: I will do it in another way, less elegant, less "react style" but working ...I hope ;)  Thanks for your help